# bulk_insert doesnt work on python anywhere

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I'm working on a webapp on python anywhere platform, with flask and flask-SQLAlchemy.

I define the ratings table:

```
class Ratings(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    section_id= db.Column(db.Integer, unique=False)
```

on my machine I use a postgres db, and I do:

```
db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(Ratings,[dict(section_id=1) for i in xrange(1,len(ratings))])
db.session.commit()
```

which works succesfuly, and load the data frame to the DB.

when I run the same code on python anywhere platform, with mysql instead of postgres, i get the message:
     `AttributeError: 'scoped_session' object has no attribute 'bulk_insert_mappings'`

does someone knows why does this happen?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using the same version of sqlalchemy on your machine as you are on PythonAnywhere?

Comment: really. are you using a virtualenv and or are you checking sqlalchemy of the correct version of python etc?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7 on both, but I didn't define virtualenv on pythonanywhere. I see that you imply this is a version issue, so I'll try to do this.